# PDO::FETCH_CLASS does not fetch into extension correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to fetch results from a mysql database into an entity class with properties representing each column. This works for first level classes but if I try to load results into an extension of this class I get double properties.

```
<?php
class Entity
{
    private $id;
}

class EntityExtended extends Entity
{}


$pdo = new \PDO(/* instance thingy */);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM entity");
$stmt->execute();

$entity = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Entity"); // Works
$entity = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "EntityExtended"); // 2 sets of properties, public $id and private $id
```

Dumping the first $entity after fetch results in `object(){private id}` and the second results in `object(){private $id, public $id}`.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, or is the only way to make a custom class loader when fetching the results?

Comment: First of all, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for a PDO related problem](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)

Comment: `private` fields aren't visible in subclasses.  Did you mean to use a `protected` field instead?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Should be easy enough to tell that this code is not supposed to work, if it does not. It's only to illustrate the problem I'm facing. Main issue with the code about is the comment inside the instantiation of the PDO object, lol.

Comment: @eggyal Yeah that is probably a solution, but that would expose the properties to the extension, which can be dangerous. I see the problem now and I will most likely close this question. To solve my issue I'll write my own class loader from the results.